# How to get cinnamon window styling

Tags: xorg, window-manager, cinnamon

I think I may have chosen `Mint-with no codecs` [from the downloads section](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php). What should I do to get the nicer `cinnamon` window styling as in this [page](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/)?. I have attached an image to show how my window title bar looks like.

[image: file]

---

```
2026:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  findp muffin
rag       8195  2757  0 17:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i muffin

2027:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  findp cinnamon
rag       1771  1214  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session --session cinnamon
rag       1848  1771  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-
launch --exit-with-session gnome-session-cinnamon
rag       1851     1  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session-cinnamon
rag       2101  1771  2 14:05 ?        00:04:42 /usr/bin/cinnamon
```

display managers:

```
2028:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  findp gdm
rag       8199  2757  0 17:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i gdm

2029:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  findp mdm
root      1213     1  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mdm
root      1214  1213  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mdm
root      1244  1214  1 14:05 tty8     00:04:16 /usr/bin/X :0 -audit 0 -auth /var/lib/mdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt8
rag       8201  2757  0 17:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i mdm
```

window managers:
before i tried installing `muffin`

```
2041:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  dpkg -l | g muffin
ii  gir1.2-muffin-3.0                           1.1.2+nadia                               amd64        GObject introspection data for Muffin
ii  libmuffin0                                  1.1.2+nadia                               amd64        window manager library from the Muffin window manager
ii  muffin-common                               1.1.2+nadia                               all          shared files for the Muffin window manager
```

I have now installed `muffin` but muffin does not start on X start up and I still have the same old style.

```
2056:rag@rag-work-laptop:~/Documents$  dpkg -l | g -i muffin
ii  gir1.2-muffin-3.0                           1.1.2+nadia                               amd64        GObject introspection data for Muffin
ii  libmuffin0                                  1.1.2+nadia                               amd64        window manager library from the Muffin window manager
ii  muffin                                      1.1.2+nadia                               amd64        lightweight GTK+ window manager
ii  muffin-common                               1.1.2+nadia                               all          shared files for the Muffin window manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed Mint after wiping Ubuntu, I remounted my backed up Ubuntu `/home` partition. Thus the theme settings for Mint were not available. So I had to go to `Preferences -> Cinnamon Settings -> Themes` to switch to a different theme. Now, I have nicer window title bars.